# Theory of API development: why create a refresh token method instead of simply ask user to relogin?

Tags: api

Most of APIs around the web provide two methods:

- login: given credentials, returns the access_token and the refresh_token
- refreshToken: given refresh_token, returns another access_token and a new refres_token.

My question is: why is so widely preferred to do login and then a possible sequence of periodic refreshToken instead of simply login again when access token expires?

Which are the benefits of a refresh versus a full login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research, I find that it's to limit the space for a Man-In-The-Middle attack.

If someone intercept your user/password you have lost. And if you send it in plain at each call, the probability will increase that someone intercept them.

If you login and then for a while use access_token , a bad actor could intercept the access_token, but at least it willl use it until it will expire.

Again, instead of relogin, remote server will use the refresh_token to obtain a new access token.

the refresh token expire after first use so it's useless to intercept.

And so on.

So for server to server, the actually best practice is

login
- receiving access_token and refresh_token

when access_token expire, use refresh_token to obtain a new access_token.

If both access_token and refresh_token expired, relogin with app_id/app_secret pair